# Regular expression to put a backslash at the end of a path, if necessary

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Why doesn't this approach work?

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace("c:\\test", "$", "\\"), "\\\\$", "\\")   //expected results
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace("c:\\test\\", "$", "\\"), "\\\\$", "\\") //not expected results
```

I would think that it would put in a backslash at the end of the line and then take out a double backslash out, if it's there.  The "$", "\" part of the regex seems to work, but not the "\\$", "\" part.

-Eric

Comment: Why do you use regex to do that?

Comment: Use `@""` to dedouble your backslashes.

Comment: Using the @ didn't seem to work for me, if I'm understand what you're saying: Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace("c:\\test\\", "$", "\\"), @"\\", @"\")  If this worked, it would strip out the \\ anywhere in the string, but I'd rather just fix it at the end.

Comment: Why would you care?  `System.IO.Path.Concat` will handle placing the proper path separators when concatenating.  If you are not concatenating then why would you care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you'll want that to concatenate at some point some file name or subdirectory name.

In that case, why bother with the slash?

Check out `Path.Combine()`

Answer (score 1):

Using a Regex for this task is overkill.  A Regex is best for matching patterns and in this case you are just matching a single character.  Yes this is a pattern but for simple actions like this using a direct character comparison is much more efficient

```
string EnsureBackSlash(string path) { 
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || path[path.Length - 1] != '\\') { 
    return path + "\";
  }

  return path;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the approach that I've taken in the past, but it seems like a RegEx could do it in just one line of code.  I'm not sure if Regex would be any faster, I suppose it depends on how you do the concatenation.

Comment: @Eric a regex is almost certainly slower here not faster.  One line of code translates to a lot of backing operations to parse the regex, execute it, build the replacement string etc ...  This is just a few IL instructions that translate to a handufl of lines of assembly.